# SQL Server Replication using Static IP

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, replication, transactional-replication

I'm trying to setup transaction replication using a static IP.

I have 2 servers: one has a static IP but other one does not. In this case can I do replication. I am able to connect to the static IP SQL Server from the other server. I also created an alias for the static IP.

I set most of it up, but at the end I got an error on the subscriber:

[image]

And if I click on <kbd>Start</kbd> then this error appears:

[image: Error comes on clicking on Start]

Answer (score 1):

This means this job is already runing. You might want to stop it and start it again, if you really need to re-run it.

`Instead:`

for a basic quick verification

I check the log reader on the publication, see if the log reader agent is reading the transactions and passing them to the distributor.

[image]

second thing

I go to the publication database and find out who is the distributor

`sp_helpdistributor`

then I connect to the distributor you got above
and run the following query to find out what is going on.

```
--Bocss Distribution
-- distribution_BOCSS is the name of my distributor database -make sure you change this to your distributor DB
--insert into tempdb.dbo.DistributorCheck
SELECT
(CASE  
    WHEN mdh.runstatus =  '1' THEN 'Start - '+cast(mdh.runstatus as varchar)
    WHEN mdh.runstatus =  '2' THEN 'Succeed - '+cast(mdh.runstatus as varchar)
    WHEN mdh.runstatus =  '3' THEN 'InProgress - '+cast(mdh.runstatus as varchar)
    WHEN mdh.runstatus =  '4' THEN 'Idle - '+cast(mdh.runstatus as varchar)
    WHEN mdh.runstatus =  '5' THEN 'Retry - '+cast(mdh.runstatus as varchar)
    WHEN mdh.runstatus =  '6' THEN 'Fail - '+cast(mdh.runstatus as varchar)
    ELSE CAST(mdh.runstatus AS VARCHAR)
END) [Run Status], 
mda.subscriber_db [Subscriber DB], 
mda.publication [PUB Name],
right(left(mda.name,LEN(mda.name)-(len(mda.id)+1)), LEN(left(mda.name,LEN(mda.name)-(len(mda.id)+1)))-(10+len(mda.publisher_db)+(case when mda.publisher_db='ALL' then 1 else LEN(mda.publication)+2 end))) [SUBSCRIBER],
CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),mdh.[time]) [LastSynchronized],
und.UndelivCmdsInDistDB [UndistCom], 
mdh.comments [Comments], 
'select * from distribution_BOCSS.dbo.msrepl_errors (nolock) where id = ' + CAST(mdh.error_id AS VARCHAR(8)) [Query More Info],
mdh.xact_seqno [SEQ_NO],
(CASE  
    WHEN mda.subscription_type =  '0' THEN 'Push' 
    WHEN mda.subscription_type =  '1' THEN 'Pull' 
    WHEN mda.subscription_type =  '2' THEN 'Anonymous' 
    ELSE CAST(mda.subscription_type AS VARCHAR)
END) [SUB Type],

mda.publisher_db+' - '+CAST(mda.publisher_database_id as varchar) [Publisher DB],
mda.name [Pub - DB - Publication - SUB - AgentID]
FROM distribution_BOCSS.dbo.MSdistribution_agents mda 
LEFT JOIN distribution_BOCSS.dbo.MSdistribution_history mdh ON mdh.agent_id = mda.id 
JOIN 
    (SELECT s.agent_id, MaxAgentValue.[time], SUM(CASE WHEN xact_seqno > MaxAgentValue.maxseq THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS UndelivCmdsInDistDB 
    FROM distribution_BOCSS.dbo.MSrepl_commands t (NOLOCK)  
    JOIN distribution_BOCSS.dbo.MSsubscriptions AS s (NOLOCK) ON (t.article_id = s.article_id AND t.publisher_database_id=s.publisher_database_id ) 
    JOIN 
        (SELECT hist.agent_id, MAX(hist.[time]) AS [time], h.maxseq  
        FROM distribution_BOCSS.dbo.MSdistribution_history hist (NOLOCK) 
        JOIN (SELECT agent_id,ISNULL(MAX(xact_seqno),0x0) AS maxseq 
        FROM distribution_BOCSS.dbo.MSdistribution_history (NOLOCK)  
        GROUP BY agent_id) AS h  
        ON (hist.agent_id=h.agent_id AND h.maxseq=hist.xact_seqno) 
        GROUP BY hist.agent_id, h.maxseq 
        ) AS MaxAgentValue 
    ON MaxAgentValue.agent_id = s.agent_id 
    GROUP BY s.agent_id, MaxAgentValue.[time] 
    ) und 
ON mda.id = und.agent_id AND und.[time] = mdh.[time] 
where mda.subscriber_db<>'virtual' -- created when your publication has the immediate_sync property set to true. This property dictates whether snapshot is available all the time for new subscriptions to be initialized. This affects the cleanup behavior of transactional replication. If this property is set to true, the transactions will be retained for max retention period instead of it getting cleaned up as soon as all the subscriptions got the change.
```

hope this helps